# translation not interpreted in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

In laravel 5, when I write this in my view:

```
@include("places.form", ["submitButton" => @lang('crud.updateModel', ['currentModelName' => $currentModelName])])
```

I get this:

```
@lang('crud.addModel', ['currentModelName' => Lugar])
```

How can I do so that it can be interpreted?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@include("tournaments.form", ["submitButton" => trans('crud.addTournament')])
```

You will get:

```
["submitButton" => 'the translated text']
```

Comment: Sorry, I just changed my question because I nedded to add params, please check the update

Answer (score 0):

`{{ }}` and `{!! !!}` are just a wrapper around `<?php echo ?>` therefore in all Blade directives you don't have to add it use type as if you are typing in PHP file! use you translation function without curly brackets, and you don't need the double quotations too:

`@include("tournaments.form", ["submitButton" =>  trans('crud.addTournament') ])`

Comment: Sorry, I just changed my question, please check the update

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro You don't have to use **Blade directive** inside another one, actually `@lang('')` is equivalent to `trans('')` therefore, just use `trans('')` instead